# passing argument to a vim "execute"

Tags: vim, arguments, parameter-passing, execute

From within Vim, I want to scan a text line by line, and pass its content to an external shell command.
For example, I have a list of names and want to say hello to each name of the list.
What I've already managed to do is as follows.

Given this text :

```
John Doe

    Jane Doe

Baby Doe
```

I can use this command to find the first name only and reuse the token in a substitute command using the backreference syntax (\0 or \1).

```
:%g/\w\+/ s//--\0--/
```

This is the output :

```
--John-- Doe

    --Jane-- Doe

--Baby-- Doe
```

What I would like to do now is to change my "substitute" command for "execute" shell command.

This command

:%g/\w\+/ **exe "!echo hello " "world"**

works fine, but how to parameterize it ?

So far, I've tried this :

:%g/\w\+/ **exe "!echo hello " \0**

and this too :

:%g/\w\+/ **exe "!echo hello " &**

with no success...

This question has a lot of value since you could then, from Vim, scan a text containing a list of directories and create them on the fly.

Comment: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Power_of_g has some examples.

Comment: Specially this one: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Redirect_g_search_output

Answer (score 3):

So here is the answer :

The following command will scan a text, trim the newlines and whitespaces to say "hello" to each name in the text :

`%g/\<\w\+\>/ y A | exe  ' !echo hello '. substitute(substitute(@a, '\n\+\s*', '', ''), '\s*\n\+', '', '') | let @a =""`

The next one will create a directory for each non-empty line of the file. This time, the *shellescape()* function is added :

`%g/\<\w\+\>/ y A | exe  ' !mkdir '. shellescape(substitute(substitute(@a, '\n\+\s*', '', ''), '\s*\n\+', '', '')) | let @a =""`

And if you need a "silent" directories creation, here is the command :

`%g/\<\w\+\>/ y A | exe  'silent !mkdir ' . shellescape(substitute(substitute(@a, '\n\+\s*', '', ''), '\s*\n\+', '', '')) | let @a =""`

**P.S. :**

You can also use the almost same command to cleanup a file (getting rid of empty lines and trimming the non-empty ones) into a new file :

`%g/\<\w\+\>/ y A | exe  'silent !echo ' . substitute(substitute(@a, '\n\+\s*', '', ''), '\s*\n\+', '', '') . ">> new_file.txt" | let @a =""`